# Why unsigned extrinsics?

Tags: extrinsic, transactions, pallet-imonline

Q1. What is the existence of `Unsigned extrinsics` for?

- I have read about it here: https://docs.substrate.io/v3/concepts/extrinsics
- But it still does not really make sense to me why it exists in Polkadot. What other examples or cases do we need to use this transaction type, other than `I'm Online` Pallet?
- From `I'm Online` pallet, why does a validator node need to send a heartbeat(unsigned tx) which tells it's online?

Q2. If Unsigned Transaction does not require any tx-fee, isn't such unsigned one vulnerable to DDoS Attack? If not, how does Polkadot protect its own network from such attacks?

Comment: Next time, if you can limit your post to one question, that would be great.

Comment: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask is a good thing to review to help you pose good questions here :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a transaction an extrinsic?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/is-a-transaction-an-extrinsic)

Answer (score 8):

That is correct - with a signed transaction [there is validation](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/concepts/tx-pool/#validity) to check the nonce, make sure the user has enough to pay for the fee, and check if the signature is valid. With an unsigned transaction you get none of this. It is up to the runtime engineer to construct their own logic such as spam prevention and create *checks* for what they consider is an invalid transaction (or valid transaction).

As an example of creating such logic, in the [I'm Online pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/im-online) there is a function [`validate_unsigned`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1532b72162240edf0d41ecb39e66e2a1f5a73b6f/frame/im-online/src/lib.rs#L551) that has a number of checks:

1. [Check if we have already received a "heartbeat" from this authority](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1532b72162240edf0d41ecb39e66e2a1f5a73b6f/frame/im-online/src/lib.rs#L553)
2. [Check to see if the session index is the same](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1532b72162240edf0d41ecb39e66e2a1f5a73b6f/frame/im-online/src/lib.rs#L558)
3. [Verify that the transaction is coming from a valid authority](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1532b72162240edf0d41ecb39e66e2a1f5a73b6f/frame/im-online/src/lib.rs#L564)
4. [Check that the signature is valid](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1532b72162240edf0d41ecb39e66e2a1f5a73b6f/frame/im-online/src/lib.rs#L574)

**Why use an unsigned transaction?**

Sometimes there are other ways to prove that a transaction is valid for your use case. If you can validate a transaction through some other means then it can open up possibilities to do things that would not be as efficient with a signed transaction such as system calls. For example, validators that need to submit a transaction to the chain such as [extrinsics that are generated on a node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ded44948e2d5a398abcb4e342b0513cb690961bb/frame/babe/src/equivocation.rs#L183) or [produced by an off-chain worker](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1532b72162240edf0d41ecb39e66e2a1f5a73b6f/frame/examples/offchain-worker/src/lib.rs#L301). The accounts generating these transactions do not typically hold funds and yet via unsigned transactions and checking where the transaction comes from either via the `TransactionSource` or against a signature, these nodes can submit extrinsics to the chain. Another point here to make is that a typical good use case for signed transactions is if you want to record the associated caller of the transaction and in the case of system calls you often do not have a need for such, you only want to make sure that the call is coming from a valid source. However, if you do have a need to know the caller there is a way to do this with unsigned transactions with a signed payload. Sometimes this is desired if you want to record the associated transaction caller, but do not want the caller be responsible for the transaction fee payment.

If you can cover all checks for validation for the unsigned transaction that you are implementing in your runtime, then there can be a lot of value in working with unsigned transactions. Another example, is to send a proof in the payload and that in combination with your validation could be sufficient for your needs.

An example of this is to sign a payload with a public key (perhaps an authority key), send it as an unsigned transaction, and have validation to check whether a provided signature matches the public key that was used to sign that payload. There is a nice how-to guide on this [here](https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/ocw/transactions/#sending-unsigned-transactions-with-signed-payloads). Additionally, the [off-chain worker example](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/examples/offchain-worker) leverages unsigned transactions with a signed payload to [check if the transaction is produced by the off-chain worker](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1532b72162240edf0d41ecb39e66e2a1f5a73b6f/frame/examples/offchain-worker/src/lib.rs#L318) and, if so, mark it as valid.

Keep in mind that regardless if it is signed or unsigned, all transactions pass through [`validate_transaction`](https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/sp_transaction_pool/runtime_api/trait.TaggedTransactionQueue.html#method.validate_transaction). This function will do some checks for the validity of a transaction but it will not check if the transactions succeed, therefore as noted [here](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/concepts/tx-pool/#validity) this could be another potential attack vector.

Comment: This is a great resource. Can we please update the links to some of these?

Answer (score 5):

> But it still does not really make sense to me why it exists in Polkadot.

I think part of building a generic and extensible blockchain framework is to support tools like this, even if we wouldn't have used them. So I would pose to you, why not?

It is important to note that unsigned extrinsics are not necessarily "without a signature". Usually, they contain a signature within the extrinsic data, instead of in an expected signature format for a signed extrinsic. This can allow for a number of behaviors:

- Skipping default behaviors like extracting a fee from the signer.
- Supporting different signature schemes which may not be natively supported by the chain.
- Supporting alternative verification methods on top of the extrinsic data.

In this case, you can think of a signed extrinsic as a set of extrinsics that go through a default pipeline of basic signature verification, fee payment, and then function dispatch. Whereas an unsigned extrinsic goes through a custom pipeline that is defined by the developer in `validate_unsigned`.

Polkadot DOES have use cases for unsigned extrinsics.

For example, Polkadot used an unsigned extrinsic to allow users that contributed in the Polkadot ICO to claim their initial DOT tokens.

In this case, we used an unsigned extrinsic for a few reasons:

- To support a secp256k1 Ethereum signature, instead of the sr25519 / ed25519 signature that Polkadot would normally expect. A secp256k1 signed extrinsic would be invalid by default on Polkadot.
- To support a feeless transaction for those initial DOT claims. It wouldn't be very friendly if users had to first buy DOT to pay for the transaction to claim their DOT. In this case, to solve the chicken and egg problem, we allowed users one free transaction to claim their DOT token in this way.
- To add the additional verification logic so that users could not abuse this transaction to spam the chain, and in result only allowing one transaction of this kind from each user.

In the case of the I'm Online pallet, we use an Unsigned Extrinsic because the nodes use a custom signing key which is rotated often and managed by the node. These keys are not expected to have any funds behind them, and we don't necessarily assume a specific cryptography used, and thus we take advantage of unsigned extrinsics in this way.