# Is a transaction an extrinsic?

Tags: extrinsic, transactions

I often see the two words used interchangeably. This has led me to read the docs:

> Extrinsics fall into three categories: inherents, signed transactions, and unsigned transactions.

- https://docs.substrate.io/v3/concepts/extrinsics

> **extrinsic**
>
> Data that is external to the blockchain and included in a block. In
> general, there are two types of extrinsics:
>
> - signed or unsigned transactions.
> - inherents inserted by block authors.

- https://docs.substrate.io/v3/getting-started/glossary/#extrinsic

> **transaction**
>
> A type of extrinsic that can be safely gossiped between nodes on the network because it can be verified through signatures or signed extensions.

- https://docs.substrate.io/v3/getting-started/glossary/#transaction

What is the difference between an extrinsic and a transaction? Is a transaction an extrinsic?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, in Substrate, transactions can generally be thought of as any piece of data that's intended for the transaction pool (and consequently, could potentially be included in a block). But there are technical nuances needed to be spelled out: the term "transaction" is in fact quite misleading, although does have merit from a user friendliness perspective (yes, technically *extrinsic pool* would be more accurate).

### Extrinsics (a.k.a. Types of Transactions)

In Substrate, a "*thing that could exist in the transaction pool*" — more commonly known as "a transaction" in the non-Substrate world — can be one of 3 distinct types, all of which fall under a broader category called  "**extrinsics**". Extrinsics is just a general term to mean *"any information that originates from *outside* a runtime"*. These are:

- **Signed transactions**: these must contain the signature of the account sending the inbound request to the runtime.
  With signed transactions, the account used to submit the request typically pays a transaction fee and must sign it using the account's private key.
- **Unsigned transactions**: these don't carry any information about who submitted the transaction, since the format of this type of transaction doesn't require a signature.
  You can define what conditions must be met for such a transaction to be valid (FRAME has an [attribute macro](https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/frame_support/attr.pallet.html#validate-unsigned-palletvalidate_unsigned-optional) to do this).
- **Inherents**: are a special type of unsigned transaction made by block authors which carry information required to build a block such as timestamps, storage proofs and uncle blocks.

### Key differences

Here are some key differences between the different types of extrinsics:

- Contrary to signed transactions, unsigned transaction types require implementing custom validation logic which can consume more resources for checking validity compared to signed transactions.
- Unsigned transactions have no economic deterrent to prevent spam or replay attacks, so custom logic must account for protecting the network from these types of transactions being misused.
- Inherents exist to address the need of adding some data to a block, whereas signed or unsigned transactions exist to potentially change the state of the blockchain.

### Examples

Here are some examples of each type of extrinsic being used in different scenarios:

| Scenario | Function call example | Type | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob wants to send some tokens to Alice and tip the block author to give this transaction more priority, using the Balances pallet. | `pallet_balances::Call::transfer` in [Polkadot](https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/8749664-2) | Signed transaction | This function can be called by any account, so we must ensure that the caller signs the transaction and pays a fee for it to be processed. |
| Charlie proposes a tip to reward Dave using the Tipping pallet. | `pallet_tips::Call::report_awesome` in [Polkadot](https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/8818237-2) | Signed transaction | This function is designed so that any account can call it, by depositing some amount and giving a reason for the tip which will be stored on-chain. |
| The on-chain council passes some motion that includes submitting a batch of valid transactions to be executed. | `pallet_utility::Call::batch` in [Polkadot](https://polkadot.subscan.io/council/131) | Unsigned transaction | This type of extrinsic can only be submitted if a majority of the council approves it and cannot be executed by any single account. |
| A validator node sends a signal to the network to indicate it's online. | `pallet_im_online::Call::heartbeat` in [Kusama](https://kusama.subscan.io/extrinsic/11232100-5) | Unsigned transaction | This can only be called by a node that's registered as a validator in the network, which is verified as part of an internal check of the function's logic and allows the node to call it without paying any fees. |
| The network wants block authoring nodes to include the current timestamp into the blocks they produce. | `pallet_timestamp::Call::now` in [Kusama](https://kusama.subscan.io/extrinsic/11232115-0) | Inherent | This is a special extrinsic that can only be included in a block by an authoring node. |
| A parachain needs to send its relay chain the validation data the relay chain expects. | `paras_inherent::Call::enter` in [Kusama](https://kusama.subscan.io/extrinsic/11232398-1) | Inherent | This is a special type of extrinsic that can only be sent by a collator node. |

Answer (score 4):

Broadly speaking an extrinsic is data that is external to the blockchain that is included in a block - think of the extrinsic root in a block with all its children ([example](https://explorer.polkascan.io/kusama/block/12457588)). You can think of an extrinsic as a broader term to encompass, as the definition says, [inherents](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/concepts/extrinsics/#inherents), signed transactions, and unsigned transactions - these are all types of extrinsics.

**Is a transaction an extrinsic?**

> Yes, in the same sense that a rose is a flower.

A transaction is a type of extrinsic.

Comment: You could also send inherents into the transaction pool, as they are unsigned transactions. However, the inherent implementation should prevent that inherents are applied more than once per block.

Comment: Inherents aren't runtime calls. Time stamps are a good example.

Comment: Edited my answer.