# Unsigned Transactions vs Signed Extensions

Tags: transactions, signed-extensions, unsigned

It seems that I can use a signed extension anywhere I can use an unsigned transaction.

Can you please explain why I would implement one over the other?

How does the transaction lifecycle differ?

The only reason I would imagine I would use an unsigned transaction would be when the submitter does not have an account.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look to Bruno's answer [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2179/why-unsigned-extrinsics). It covers both rationale and transaction lifecycle for unsigned extrinsics.