# Why does ImOnline use ValidateUnsigned over SignedExtension?

Tags: transactions, pallet-imonline

From `ValidateUnsigned`:

> Note that any checks done here are only used for determining the
> validity of the transaction for the transaction pool. During block
> execution phase one need to perform the same checks anyway, since this
> function is not being called.

Which leads me to the question, is writing a `SignedExtension` any better in code than `ValidateUnsigned` since both provide the same pre-dispatch and tx validation checks. Maybe `SignedExtension` is more general but as far as I can see, for unsigned tx, they make no difference.

I also ask this because `pallet-im-online` uses `ValidateUnsigned` instead of `SignedExtension` and I wonder the motivation behind the choice.

Comment: Take a look at this https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2179/why-unsigned-extrinsics

Comment: funny i was just reading that lol!

Comment: @Purple_Turtle can you please update your question to be more specific, or close it if you think the answer above answers your question.

Comment: I've updated my title and I don't believe the commented link answers my question but does provide a fantastic overview of unsigned TX handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SignedExtension` currently can not be used as a replacement for `ValidateUnsigned`. This has historical reasons, `ValidateUnsigned` was added before `SignedExtension`. There is an [issue](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/4419) to merge both of them.